# Syntax Highlighting Pager

Tags: command-line, syntax-highlighting, pager

Right now, I use `most` as my pager.  While it has helpful syntax highlighting for `man` pages, it lacks colored syntax highlighting for anything else (I'm specifically looking for diff/C++).

Meanwhile, `pygments` is a wonderful program.  I can easily make colorized output with it:

```
# ./pygmentize -f console256 ${file}
hg diff | ./pygmentize -f console256 -l diff
```

Now, I would like to be able to page the output, so I just use:

```
# ./pygmentize -f console256 ${file} | most
hg diff | ./pygmentize -f console256 -l diff | most
```

At this point, most dumps all the colorizing control characters to my screen like so:

```
^[[38;5;28;01mclass^[[39;00m ^[[38;5;21;01mheap_allocator^[[39;00m
{
^[[38;5;28;01mpublic^[[39;00m^[[38;5;241m:^[[39m
```

This is, of course, unreadable.  I looked though the `man` page for `most`, but I couldn't find any "Hey, show those control characters as colors instead of printing them" options.  `less` has the same garbage behavior as `most`, but `more` shows the colors perfectly fine, with the obvious limitations of being `more`.

Is there a pager that supports syntax highlighting or some crazy combination of parameters and programs I can string together to make this work?  Ultimately, I would like to get diffs and logs from Mercurial to be highlighted, so maybe there is a shortcut in there...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`less -R` shows ANSI color sequences as-is (instead of expanding to caret notation). That'll make syntax highlighting work!

You can also create an environment variable `LESS=-R` to make this the default behavior. Similarly for other options; see `man less`.

Comment: I don't see this behavior on mac

Answer (score 10):

Might I suggest `vimpager`?

First off, recent `vim` distributions (I believe 6.0 and above) *come* with a pager-esque-mode script. It's quite simple and functional, and operates similarly to `less`. Try: `vim '+help less' +only`.

Even better, however, Rafael Kitover has written a much more robust and powerful script called `vimpager`. It's available [on GitHub](https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager) (or [vimscripts](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1723)). If you are on OS X and using Homebrew, it's as easy as `brew install vimpager`.

At that point, you can simply `set $PAGER=vimpager`, or even `alias less=vimpager`. It works excellently.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Look for [bat: A cat(1) clone with wings](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat).

`bat` supports syntax highlighting for a large number of programming and markup languages.

It is not a pager, but it automatically redirects output to `less` if needed.

[image]

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: @Zoethetransgirl `bat FILENAME`

Comment: this works for me better than vimpager. for some reason bat wont syntax highlight typescript files though

Answer (score 2):

You might try using jed. Yes, it's a text editor, not a pager, but it's quite lightweight and the default install contains excellent colorschemes for a wide variety of file types and languages.

Comment: Nice - jed supports piping into the buffer (vim and regular emacs do not).  How does one turn on syntax highlighting in jed?  If I `jed ${FILE}`, highlighting works, but not when I `cat ${FILE} | jed`

Comment: I don't think that's possible. It's actually a really hard problem, since it's fairly straightforward to come up with short programs that are syntactically valid in many languages. The mode detection, as in most editors, is just based on file extensions. Easiest way would probably be to just pipe stdout to a file with an appropriate extension.

Comment: What is the command sequence to turn on syntax highlighting once the program has already started?  I'm not familiar with emacs derivatives.

Comment: Not sure actually. Been a while since I've really used it. Doing an `info jed` brings up fairly extensive documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Jed has syntax highlighting modes for different languages, simillar to the emacs ones. For example if you piped a C program to it, you can turn on the highlighting by pressing '**ESC**', then '**x**', then typing '**c-mode**' . If it is a php program - change the last part to '**php-mode**' and so on ...